# Convert Interface to different type

Tags: java

How would I convert an interface to another type?

Let's say i have an interface of type 'Cars' and
another one of type 'trucks'.
I would like to convert this interface to type 'Vehicles'.

How would i go about solving that?

Comment: Why should you want to convert interfaces?

Comment: You simply cant.

Comment: @B001ᛦ because i already have instances of both and would like to get them in one

Comment: Interfaces can extend other interfaces so assuming I understand you correctly, just create a new interfaces `Vehicle` (no plural), move the common method declarations to that new interface and let the other interfaces extend it. Then all classes that implement either of the two also implement the new interface. If you want to get rid of them you then should be able to replace them with the new interface in your code on a per-use basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an interface `Vehicle` with some methods. And two interfaces `Car` and `Truck` with some additional methods. And you want to also use the methods of the `Vehicle` in the `Car` and `Truck` interfaces?

If that's the case, you can `extends` interfaces, similar as you would extend classes:

```
interface Vehicle{
  // Some methods
}

interface Car extends Vehicle{
  // Some methods
}

interface Truck extends Vehicle{
  // Some methods
}
```

Now if you have a class like this:

```
class Bmw implements Car{
  // Overwrite methods of both the Cars and Vehicles interfaces
}
```

And if you want you can save the `Bmw` in a list of `Vehicles`:

```
List<Vehicle> allVehicles = new ArrayList<>();
Vehicle myBmw = new Bmw();
allVehicles.add(myBmw);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Change all classes which currently implement `Car` or `Truck` to now implement `Vehicle` instead.
2. Make `Car` and `Truck` extend your new interface `Vehicle`.

Eg. If you currently have:

```
class A implements Car {
    public void carDrive(){ ... }
}

class B implements Truck {
    public void truckDrive(){ ... }
}
```

You could change it to:

```
class A implements Vehicle {
    public void vehicleDrive(){ ... }
}

class B implements Vehicle {
    public void vehicleDrive(){ ... }
}
```